# Why isn't layout inflater available in recycler view?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

i'm having trouble at recycler view. When i want to add layout inflater, android does not respond like this

```
import android.content.Context
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class MyAdapter(var ctx: Context): RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> (){


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        var myRoot: layoutInflater
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elOii.png)

But when in other activity, layout inflater appears by itself, like this one

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03yuE.png)

What should i do with this?

Comment: it's magic ...  or just one class has such property and other doesn't ... you need to know which class has such property and then try to get its instance in adapter ...

Comment: you're missing something quite basic here. when i write `val foo: bar`, what does this mean ?

Comment: also first google result for `RecyclerView` returns an official example which shows how you can to obtain layout inflater - is your internet search engine not working? it take less time use it than asking here

Answer (score 0):

```
var myRoot: layoutInflater
```

This is a grammar error.
layoutInflater is not a type of a parameter.
This is not type, it's an object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get layout inflater from context in adapter, like this:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) {
    return CustomViewHolder(parent.inflateView(R.layout.item_view))
}
    
private fun ViewGroup.inflateView(@LayoutRes res: Int): View {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(res, this, false)
}
```